# Support multiple socket connections with Erlang via Web

Tags: sockets, nginx, erlang

Suppose I have an API app which is open to connect to users apps over the web. Now, say, 10.000 users connect to it with their client apps.

I wonder, how do I manage 10000 simultaneous connections? I mean, do I need to have 10000 ports in my system for them to connect, like, 1000-11000?

How will it work if I use nginx or apache as a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

No, you wouldn't need 10000 ports. This question is a bit broad in the sense that we don't know your hardware configuration.

If you have multiple servers, this can be completed with relative ease using multiple upstream servers to which you'll proxy the connection. On each of these servers, you'll bind to a unix socket to reduce the overhead of the connection (so you're not using additional ports as well).

Nginx configuration will have to be tweaked depending on the hardware you're running (things like the number of worker processes and worker connections). You'll also have to configure your keep_alive timeouts and caching policies. Enabling compression can be beneficial, but it may consume too many CPU cycles if you set it too high. So again, it's hardware dependent.

Another thing to note will be your gateway interface (eg wsgi, fcgi, uWSGI, etc..). These too have configurations which will need to be tweaked. In theory, these connection interfaces could each bind to their own socket, and so you could simulate having multiple application servers on a single server. However, this won't improve the situation.

One last comment:
If you're running a single sever and want to achieve 10000 concurrent connections, Nginx will be able to handle the traffic in most cases. The bottleneck occurs at your app server. Many a time it can't handle the load. In this case, try to either optimise your codebase or acquire another server (or upgrade the hardware).

See this [post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/) for tuning in Nginx. I cannot comment on an Apache setup.

In summary, you'll only need one port for the incoming connection if you're using unix sockets. You'll need 2 or more if you're going to proxy the connection to your app server which is binding on a different port.

Disclaimer:
I'm not an expert, but I attempted to answer anyway.